# Find top three integer numbers

Tags: arrays, c, integer

I need to find top 3 of 10 integer numbers without using arrays.
I must find index of them and print array number with indexing.

For example if array is {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

I must find that first=9, second=8,third=7 and print array as:

array[first]

array[second]

array[third].

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  double arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
  double s0 = 0, s1 = 1, s2 = 2, s3 = 3, s4 = 4, s5 = 5, s6 = 6, s7 = 7, s8 = 8,
         s9 = 9;
  int first = 0, second=0,third=0;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (s1 >= s0 && s1 >= s2 && s1 >= s3 && s1 >= s4 && s1 >= s5 && s1 >= s6 &&
        s1 >= s7 && s1 >= s8 && s1 >= s9)
      first = 1;
    if (s2 >= s0 && s2 >= s1 && s2 >= s3 && s2 >= s4 && s2 >= s5 && s2 >= s6 &&
        s2 >= s7 && s2 >= s8 && s2 >= s9)
      first = 2;
    if (s3 >= s0 && s3 >= s1 && s3 >= s2 && s3 >= s4 && s3 >= s5 && s3 >= s6 &&
        s3 >= s7 && s3 >= s8 && s3 >= s9)
      first = 3;
    if (s4 >= s0 && s4 >= s1 && s4 >= s2 && s4 >= s3 && s4 >= s5 && s4 >= s6 &&
        s4 >= s7 && s4 >= s8 && s4 >= s9)
      first = 4;
    if (s5 >= s0 && s5 >= s1 && s5 >= s2 && s5 >= s3 && s5 >= s4 && s5 >= s6 &&
        s5 >= s7 && s5 >= s8 && s5 >= s9)
      first = 5;
    if (s6 >= s0 && s6 >= s1 && s6 >= s2 && s6 >= s3 && s6 >= s4 && s6 >= s5 &&
        s6 >= s7 && s6 >= s8 && s6 >= s9)
      first = 6;
    if (s7 >= s0 && s7 >= s1 && s7 >= s2 && s7 >= s3 && s7 >= s4 && s7 >= s5 &&
        s7 >= s6 && s7 >= s8 && s7 >= s9)
      first = 7;
    if (s8 >= s0 && s8 >= s1 && s8 >= s2 && s8 >= s3 && s8 >= s4 && s8 >= s5 &&
        s8 >= s6 && s8 >= s7 && s8 >= s9)
      first = 8;
    if (s9 >= s0 && s9 >= s1 && s9 >= s2 && s9 >= s3 && s9 >= s4 && s9 >= s5 &&
        s9 >= s6 && s9 >= s7 && s9 >= s8)
      first = 9;
  }
  printf("First: %g", arr[first]);
  return 0;
}
```

This finds first element of array. How could I find second and third element? Restriction of not using arrays makes this tough.

Comment: Side note: Why are you using `double` to represent integer values? Why not simply use `int`?

Comment: The expression `arr[first]` is using the array? Are you allowed to do that? Are you allowed to use the array `arr`, but make no other arrays? Or is the printing the only place in your program where you are allowed to use the array?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yes, I'm allowed to use array only when printing

Comment: I need to use this program with double numbers, but to make it easier in the question I used integer numbers (reason for making double arr instead of int arr)

Comment: Is the range of the integers limited to 0 - 9? Also, can there be duplicates like {0,1,2,3,4,5,7,7,9,9}?

Comment: range of numbers (they can be also double) is not limited and there can be duplicates

Comment: Does not using arrays include not going through the array with a pointer or is it limited to not using the index operator [ ] ?

Comment: it's not allowed to use index operator and as well pointers to array, as I said restriction of not using arrays makes this almost impossible to solve, but the way I think it would be solved is by something similar to my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main( void )
{
    double arr[] =
        { 17.1, 12.3, 7.2, 35.7, 14.2, 12.4, 6.9, 19.1, 34.9, 5.5 };

    //This declaration has been modified to use the array only to
    //ensure consistency with the array. I do not consider this to
    //be cheating. This declaration can be replaced with the
    //original code and the program will still work.
    double
        s0 = arr[0], s1 = arr[1], s2 = arr[2], s3 = arr[3],
        s4 = arr[4], s5 = arr[5], s6 = arr[6], s7 = arr[7],
        s8 = arr[8], s9 = arr[9];

    int first = 0, second = 0, third = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        int largest_index;
        double *p_largest;

        for ( int j = 0; j < 10; j++ )
        {
            double *p;

            //the following loop effectively does "p = &arr[j]", without
            //actually using the array, but instead making the pointer
            //point to the corresponding lone variable instead
            switch ( j )
            {
                case 0:
                    p = &s0;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    p = &s1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    p = &s2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    p = &s3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    p = &s4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    p = &s5;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    p = &s6;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    p = &s7;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    p = &s8;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    p = &s9;
                    break;
           }

           //determine whether *p is the largest value in the
           //array
           if (
                *p >= s0 && *p >= s1 && *p >= s2 && *p >= s3 &&
                *p >= s4 && *p >= s5 && *p >= s6 && *p >= s7 &&
                *p >= s8 && *p >= s9
            )
            {
                largest_index = j;
            }
        }

        //This "switch" statement effectively does
        //"p_largest = &arr[largest_index];", but does not
        //point inside the array. Instead, it points to the
        //corresponding lone variable.
        switch ( largest_index )
        {
            case 0:
                p_largest = &s0;
                break;
            case 1:
                p_largest = &s1;
                break;
            case 2:
                p_largest = &s2;
                break;
            case 3:
                p_largest = &s3;
                break;
            case 4:
                p_largest = &s4;
                break;
            case 5:
                p_largest = &s5;
                break;
            case 6:
                p_largest = &s6;
                break;
            case 7:
                p_largest = &s7;
                break;
            case 8:
                p_largest = &s8;
                break;
            case 9:
                p_largest = &s9;
                break;
        }

        //set "first", "second" or "third", depending on which
        //loop iteration we currently are in
        switch ( i )
        {
            case 0:
                first  = largest_index;
                break;
            case 1:
                second = largest_index;
                break;
            case 2:
                third  = largest_index;
                break;
        }

        //set highest number to lowest possible number, so that
        //it won't be the highest again in the next iteration of
        //the loop
        *p_largest = -DBL_MAX;
    }

    printf( "First:  %g\n", arr[first] );
    printf( "Second: %g\n", arr[second] );
    printf( "Third:  %g\n", arr[third] );
}
```

This program has the following (correct) output:

```
First:  35.7
Second: 34.9
Third:  19.1
```

This solution works by setting the highest found value to the lowest possible value (which is `-DBL_MAX`), so that the next iteration of the loop will not find the same value again as the highest value, but will instead find the next highest value.

For comparison, here is my much cleaner solution which uses arrays instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main( void )
{
    double arr[] =
        { 17.1, 12.3, 7.2, 35.7, 14.2, 12.4, 6.9, 19.1, 34.9, 5.5 };

    double largest_values[3];

    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        double largest_value = -DBL_MAX;
        int largest_index;

        for ( int j = 0; j < 10; j++ )
        {
            if ( arr[j] >= largest_value )
            {
                largest_value = arr[j];
                largest_index = j;
            }
        }

        largest_values[i] = largest_value;
        arr[largest_index] = -DBL_MAX;
    }

    printf( "First:  %g\n", largest_values[0] );
    printf( "Second: %g\n", largest_values[1] );
    printf( "Third:  %g\n", largest_values[2] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a decent algorithm

```cpp
int* top_3(const int* arr_of_10) {
  static int top_3[3];
  int next_highest = 0;
  
  for (int appended = 0; appended < 3; appended++) {
    int highest_of = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
      if ((highest < arr_of_10[index]) && ((highest < next_highest) || !next_highest)) {
        highest = arr_of_10[index];
      }
    }
    top_3[appended] = highest;
    next_highest = highest;
  }
  return top_3;
}
```

Comment: you are using auxiliary array `top_3[3];` which is not allowed

Comment: Fuex Follets, `return top_3;` returns a pointer to `int top_3[3];`.  `top_3` is not longer valid once the function ends.  Result: undefined behavior (UB).

Comment: I just realized, I needed to have `static` identifier

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way of doing it that iterates over each element, and moves it up the rankings of third, second and first until the index holding that rank points to a larger or equal value. You will notice that I am initializing the indexes with -1, I do this because if they all started with 0 and 0 was in the top 2 (it would be fine if it was the third), then no other numbers would replace it and your top three would all be the initial value, even if there was only one of that value. (I will add another work around below)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int first = -1, second = -1, third = -1;

    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (third == -1 || arr[i] > arr[third]) { //greater than third
            third = i;
            if (second == -1 || arr[i] > arr[second]) { //than second
                temp = second;
                second = third;
                third = temp;
                if (first == -1 || arr[i] > arr[first]) { //than first
                    temp = first;
                    first = second;
                    second = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("First: %d\n", arr[first]);
    printf("Second: %d\n", arr[second]);
    printf("Third: %d\n", arr[third]);

    return 0;
}
```

You will notice that each of the if statements first have to check if the rank hasn't been filled (== -1), which is not ideal. To avoid this we can initialize the three ranks to point to the smallest value, which takes computational power to find, but if you count the integer comparisons, its less.

```
//find index of the min
int min = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < arr[min]) {
        min = i;
    }
}

//set each rank to the index of the min
int first = min, second = min, third = min;
```

This would be inserted into the fist code block in place of the original initialization of the three ranks. You would then be able to remove the three occurrences of `rank == -1 ||` in the if statements.

Comment: I'm allowed to use array only when printing

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a homework assignment or something (because you say allowed), but I would check that you are interpreting the problem right. The only reason they would make you do this is if its a class on how to write bad code. Whenever your comparing numbers (or anything), you want them in an iterable data structure.

Comment: @art500: I fully agree that this assignment does not make much sense. In my answer, I provided a solution which does not use arrays, but afterwards, I also provided a proper solution which does use arrays. I did this to show how much better the solution is that uses arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a boneheaded approach but given your restrictions, how about something like this?

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        double s0 = 0, s1 = 1, s2 = 2, s3 = 3, s4 = 4, s5 = 5, s6 = 6, s7 = 7, s8 = 8, s9 = 9;
        var arr = new double[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        int first = 0, second=0, third=0;
        
        first = FindMax(s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, -1, -1);
        second = FindMax(s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, first, -1);
        third = FindMax(s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, first, second);
        
        Console.WriteLine(arr[first]);
        Console.WriteLine(arr[second]);
        Console.WriteLine(arr[third]);
    }

    private static int FindMax(
        double s0, 
        double s1, 
        double s2, 
        double s3, 
        double s4, 
        double s5, 
        double s6, 
        double s7, 
        double s8,
        double s9,
        int indexOneToIgnore,
        int indexTwoToIgnore){
        
        double max = 0;
        int indexOfMax = 0;
        
        if(Math.Max(max, s0) > max && indexOneToIgnore != 0 && indexTwoToIgnore != 0)
        {
            max = s0;
            indexOfMax = 0;
        }
        if(Math.Max(max, s1) > max && indexOneToIgnore != 1 && indexTwoToIgnore != 1)
        {
            max = s1;
            indexOfMax = 1;
        }
        if(Math.Max(max, s2) > max && indexOneToIgnore != 2 && indexTwoToIgnore != 2)
        {
            max = s2;
            indexOfMax = 2;
        }


...

        return indexOfMax;
    }
```

Full example here: [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wolBkm).

Could be shortened quite a bit by moving the if statements to a separate function but since you´d need to adopt it to C++ anyway I´d leave that to you.

Comment: here is in C if you want to edit your question https://onlinegdb.com/yTUot8lCk